# NFC Tag - Taps counter

Tags: android, touch, nfc, counter

Hy!

I am working on my NFC project for my diploma thesis and I want to make 2 things:

1) When I tap NFC tag with my phone I want that browser on my phone connect me to my website.

2) I want to make that my NFC tag count numbers of taps so I can later read that number with my android app and send it to database on my server, so I can make statistics about how many times my NFC tag has been tapped.

I have accomplished my first task and my phone browser propertly display my website when I tap NFC tag but now I have problem with my second task. I have searched on internet for some tutorials and I havent found any good tutorial how to programm NFC tag to count numbers of taps and its not as simple as with website url, so I am asking myself, maybe its not even possible to make it. I think, if NFC tag can save whole URL of website it must be possible to save single integer number and do basic `Number_of_taps + = 1` thing.

If anyone knows good solution or link of some good tutorial pls post it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application which is enabled on your device, you're able to write numbers on the NFC tag of course. To do it, you'll have to detect the tag, authentificate if necessary, get the number you've stored, increment it and write it into the memory's tag.
You can find basic informations about tags and I/O operations here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/TagTechnology.html

Answer (score 0):

Combine the read and write examples [here](https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/#git/ndeftools-util/src/org/ndeftools/util/activity) and you should be able to make a counter which increments a number stored on a tag. See also the solution to [this](https://github.com/skjolber/Fagmote/tree/master/Android/Near%20Field%20Communications) workshop.